# MS Access: Update the values in a table to match the ID fields of another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in my MS Access database:

1) tblLines

- LineID
- Line
- LineName

2) tblTripTimes

- TripTimesID
- Line
- Time

The tblTripTimes times table was imported into MS Access from a transit software program, and tblLines I created in MS Access. The **Line** column in each table share identical values; however, I'd prefer the tblTripTimes.Line values be replaced with the primary key values in tblLines.LineID.

For example:

**Before**

```
tblLines           tblTripTimes
---------------    ------------------------
LineID | Line      TripId |  Line |  Time
  1        1         234      3      13:00
  2        2         235      1      09:00 
  3        2A        236      2      17:17
  4        2B        237      2B     07:30 
  5        3         238      2A     21:36
```

**After**

```
tblLines           tblTripTimes
---------------    ------------------------
LineID | Line      TripId |  Line |  Time
  1        1         234      5      13:00
  2        2         235      1      09:00 
  3        2A        236      2      17:17
  4        2B        237      4      07:30 
  5        3         238      3      21:36
```

I've tried creating an update query that would match tblTripTimes.Line with tblLines.Line, then replace the values in tblTripTimes.Line with the values in the tblLines.LineID column. Being a rookie I'm at a complete loss.

Can someone please help?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple update query:

```
UPDATE tblLines INNER JOIN tblTripTimes ON tblLines.Line = tblTripTimes.Line
SET tblTripTimes.Line = tblLines.LineID
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was much simpler than what I thought.